# larg matrix multiplication in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication

I have memory limitation for multiplication of two sparse matrices A and B (ie A*B).

A is 22164*5, and B is 5*296277.
The MATLAB error is:'Requested 22164x296277 (48.9GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference...'  .

note that my memory is 8GB.

is there a solution?

Comment: Judging from the error message, it seems that `A` are `B` are sparse but very dense. In that case it may be difficult to solve your problem. What do `nnz(A)/numel(A)` and `nnz(B)/numel(B)` return? Are you sure that `A` and `B` have the `sparse` attribute (check with `whos A B`)?

Comment: What are you using `A*B` for? Could you use `A` and `B` instead?

Comment: nnz(A)/numel(A) return: 0.106 and nnz(B)/numel(B) return: 1.

Comment: See [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019)